# Explain the error

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

below is a c++ code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
    public:
          virtual int f() const { cout << "Base::f()\n"; }
          virtual void f(string) const {}
          virtual void g() const {}
};

class Derived4 : public Base {
    public:
          int f(int) const { cout << "Derived4::f()\n"; }
};
int main() {
    string s ("hello");
    Derived4 d4;
    Base *br = &d4; //line 5
    //br->f(1);//line 6
    br->f();//line 7
    br->f(s);//line 8
}
```

the code is working fine ,but line 6 is an error . the code is calling base versions of the f(). i have also read that if u redefine the function in derived class , all the base class def of that func all hidden? am i wrong?

Comment: first of all include<string>

Comment: Explain _which_ error? What is the compiler telling you?  Which line is line 6?  At first glance I see five errors.

Comment: @MooingDuck can you state the five errors? please

Comment: @0x499602D2: I _highly_ doubt that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of compilation errors. Keeping it aside -

Polymorphism is a run-time concept. So, function call dispatch mechanism happens at run-time. You should have same member function signatures in base and derived classes for it to work.

```
br->f(1);//line 6
```

At compile time, compiler tries to match with the signature of the member function available in `Base`. In this case, `f(string)` accepts string type and hence the error.

> i have also read that if u redefine the function in derived class ,
>   all the base class def of that func all hidden?

That is a different scenario.

```
struct foo{
   fooBar(int i);
};

struct bar:foo{
   fooBar(std::string);
};

void test()
{
    bar obj;
    obj.fooBar(11); // bar class hides the member function foo::fooBar(int)
}
```

Comment: well that means, late binding can occur for only those functions which are both in base and derived( with the same arg and return type) .??

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, I agree. Can you please tell me which part of my answer suggest its possibility ? I will try to be more accurate in the next edit.

Comment: @Mahesh: you should have indicated that the obj.fooBar(11) will not compile because of the fact that that signature is hidden.